# Как удалять с помощью id в Sugar ORM?

Tags: java, android, orm, sugarorm

У меня есть записи в базе данных , как удалять их по ID?
пример типа

```
Korz korz = Korz.findById(Korz.class, 1);
korz.delete();
```

выдаёт ошибку

```
public class Korz extends SugarRecord {
    int price;
    int image;
    private Long id;
    @Unique
    String name;


    public Korz() {
    }

    public Korz(String name, int price, int image ) {
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
        this.image = image;


    }
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Korz{" +
                "name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", mail='" + price + '\'' +
                ", image='" + image + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Comment: Всегда прикладывайте текст ошибки в подобных вопросах